# Freely available and re-distributable weather observations over the US?

Tags: meteorology, weather-forecasting, open-data

I am looking for a (small) data set of weather observations for a few (say 5-20) weather stations in the US, with observations of precipitation, temperature and wind speed for the year 2016. The data should be freely available and downloadable - and, should be allowed to be re-distributed to third parties, since I would like to use it as an example data set in an R package to demonstrate some methodology I have implemented.

Is there such a data set?

Comment: Hourly observations or daily highs/lows/precip?

Comment: Check out fluxnet http://fluxnet.fluxdata.org/ and the reddyproc package

Comment: Weather underground might have something, https://www.wunderground.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such a dataset can be found via the NCDC. [Here](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/land-based-station-data/land-based-datasets) is the main gateway. My 'go to' place for high temporal resolution data from NCDC is the [5-minute ASOS data](ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/asos-fivemin/6401-2016/).

Comment: You can extract a subset of the stations for your 'small' dataset.

Comment: Thanks! Where can I find information on the data license / policies regarding the re-use? Specifically, how can I be sure that I am allowed to download, re-package, and re-distribute a part of that dataset?

Comment: @user3825755 I'd think, as long as you're keeping it to US datasets, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_status_of_work_by_the_U.S._government) applies (NCDC is part of NOAA).  But hopefully they do have a specific statement (as some international data, at the least, is subject to additional complexities of the provider's copyrights... and just maybe the NWS has rare deals with private locations to only share data in certain forms.  But never across any such issues!)

Comment: I do slightly draw back on my previous post, as [these details](https://www.cendi.gov/publications/04-8copyright.html#30) show there's a few complications to that (indeed, OpenStreetMaps is also cautious on such) .  So can understand if you need something clearer.  But for what it's worth, I can certainly vouch the data is entire open.

Comment: @user3825755 I think [this](https://www.weather.gov/disclaimer) is what you're looking for, with the mentioned [limitations on international data usage](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/customer-support) (bottom left section of page).

Comment: Ok, thanks, this looks fine.  `They can be used within the United States or for noncommercial international activities without restriction. Redistribution of these data by others must provide this same notification.`