# What (if any) "in-situ instrumentation" is on the Brunt Ice Shelf that will detect its splitting and breaking away?

Tags: glaciology, remote-sensing, antarctica, gnss, gps

The BBC News article [Antarctic: No role for climate in Halley iceberg splitting](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-47817510) says:

> With no-one on the ice surface, notice of any breakaway will have to come from **automated in-situ instrumentation** and from spacecraft observations.

What (if any) "in-situ instrumentation" is on the Brunt Ice Shelf that will detect its splitting and breaking away?

[This answer](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/13251/6031) to my question *The giant 6,000 km2 iceberg A-68; will ground-truth telemetry supplement satellite tracking data?* suggests that there was no GPS tracking of iceberg A-68 (which still surprises me!) but does the Brunt Ice Shelf have GPS and automatic telemetry?

Note: The BBC article contains the following possibly helpful links:

> [This remote-sensing data is processed by the ENVEO (Environmental Earth Observation) company](http://projects.enveo.at/Brunt/), in Innsbruck, Austria; and ENVEO staff are co-authors on [a new paper with the Northumbria team that is under review in The Cryosphere journal](https://www.the-cryosphere-discuss.net/tc-2019-46/).

---

[image: Brunt Ice Shelf BBC]

Source: NASA, LandSat, USGS, [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-47817510)

Comment: related: [Is "Chasm One" the official name for this feature on the Brunt Ice Shelf?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/16653/6031)

Answer (score 2):

You can get detailed information on the [British Antarctic Survey's](https://www.bas.ac.uk/project/brunt-ice-shelf-movement/) website. BAS have installed 15 GPS instruments and also monitor the chasm with telemetered radar that profiles the area around the chasm. Chasms are cracks in the ice shelf that penetrate through the shelf to the sea.